# By using swift, convert User's objectId as pointer to another class in synchronous by parse.com

Tags: swift, parse-platform

In my Swift app, I am using parse.com for login. In USER class, "ObjectId" created for each and every registrations. Another class, contact form is there. That details saved in "contact_form". In the contact form, there is a object called "userId" which is pointer to USER class. That UserId data type is not in string. I don't know how to save objectId of User's class as Pointer in contact_form class. Kindly guide me. I don't want this parse code run as asynchronous. I want this to be run in synchronous. My Code is below.

//MY CODING

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "User")
query.whereKey("email", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser().email)
var obj_arr : NSArray = query.findObjects() //1 obj retrived
if let objects = obj_arr as? [PFObject] { // Synchronous
    for object in objects {
        var query_msg = PFQuery(className: "contact_form")
        query_msg.whereKey("userId", equalTo: object.objectId) // Storing as String Error received. How to store as pointer.
    }
}
```

Kindly guide me.

Comment: Why syncronous / blocking?

Comment: You will need to create a PFRelation on Custom Class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`object.objectId` is a String, but you want to match on a Pointer. Try changing

`query_msg.whereKey("userId", equalTo: object.objectId)`

to

`query_msg.whereKey("userId", equalTo: object)`